# Is there an expression for a seller's talk to a customer?

Tags: expressions

"Welcome to our store!" "We have the best hamburgers in the market which we have been cooking for generation after generation with no equal!" "The best prices around for such a complete piece of work" et cetra.

Is there a good expression for such words?

Comment: It's *sales talk*

Comment: [*Spiel*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/spiel), perhaps.

Comment: Both are nice, spiel is a word I've never heard but it fits perfectly. Thanks you two

Comment: Definitely "spiel".

Comment: We call it "fluff" in my shop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common term (in AmE) is *[sales pitch](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/sales-pitch)*

> an argument or other persuasion used in selling

*Collins*

It is also used in other contexts where persuasion is the purpose.

> a speech that is given in order to persuade someone to buy something
>
> *It's not clear if voters liked the governor's sales pitch enough to reelect her.*

*[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sales%20pitch)*

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that *pitch* is also used as a verb, meaning *deliver a sales pitch for* and there is also the not-terribly-common term *pitchman.*